# Is this a correct approach to populate the properties of an App Context in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I've successfully created two contexts, one for each of two different modules I've built in React using functional components and React Hooks.  It has become apparent that there is shared data, required by most/all components I'll be building.  Rather than making GET calls with every single top-level component, I want to refactor this common data and store it in an `AppContext`.  This data will never change in a session for each user.

At first I tried having all of the population code directly in `AppContext` but that didn't work because the context wasn't yet initialized.  So then I created a component called `InitAppData` and wrapped it like this in `App.js`:

```
<AppContext>
  <Router />
  <InitAppData />
</AppContext>
```

`InitAppData` itself is pretty standard:

```
const InitAppData = () => {
  const { appStore,
          updateAppStore } = useContext(AppContext);

  // Populate the AWS Auth Token
  useGetAwsAuthToken();

  // Retrieve the Roles with a GET useFetch call
  const [{ data: rolesData, 
          status: rolesStatus,
          isLoading: rolesIsLoading, 
          isError: rolesIsError }] = useFetch(
    `${API_ROOT()}acct_mgmt/roles`,
    { }
  );

  // Process & populate the fetched Roles
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!rolesIsLoading && rolesStatus === 200) {
      appStore.roles = rolesData.roles;
    }
  }, [rolesIsLoading, rolesStatus]);

  // ... more population to go here ...

    return (null);
}

export default InitAppData;
```

Everything seems to be getting populated correctly.  I realize that this is perhaps a little unconventional but it is following the same pattern I've used previously of pairing a context with a component, whereby the latter interacts with the former.

Interested in everyone's thoughts on this approach.  If there is a better practice, I'm always interested to learn!

Comment: Could you provide some code of how you intend to do it?

Comment: @cbdev420 I just expanded my question with code as per your request.

Comment: What do you mean by "self-populate itself" ?

Comment: Also, could you provide an example of how you would consume that context?

Comment: I think I've answered my own question.  It appears that I can't populate anything in `AppContext` until it's initialized.  I've tried several things to wait for this initialization while within `AppContext` but none seem to work.  So instead I think I'll launch the population (of the `AppContext` properties) from a high-level child component.

Comment: Yes. From what you're describing, I think it's how I usually do it. I have some context providers living inside my `App.js` file. Like `AuthContext` for authentication purposes.

Comment: @cbdev420 I rewrote my question based on your feedback and my own findings.  Very interested in your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps. That's kind of what I've been doing and so far it's working alright.

Link to the Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-currying-7fpyw

**index.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import AppContext from "./AppContext";
import AllRoutes from "./AllRoutes";

function mockAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        resolve({
          propA: "This is some propA value",
          propB: "This is some propB value"
        }),
      1500
    )
  );
}

function App() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    callMockAPI();
  }, []);

  async function callMockAPI() {
    const response = await mockAPI();
    setAppState(response);
    setLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appState}>
      {loading ? (
        <div>I am waiting for the API to respond...</div>
      ) : (
        <Router>
          <AllRoutes />
        </Router>
      )}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**AppContext.js**

```
import React from "react";

const AppContext = React.createContext(null);

export default AppContext;
```

**AllRoutes.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import SomeComponent from "./SomeComponent";

function AllRoutes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/someComp" component={SomeComponent} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default AllRoutes;
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this.  One question: Imagine your app has to login before `callMockAPI` is run or run a 2nd time after login.  Would it handle this correctly?

Comment: I just realized that I can't quite do it the way you have because my team's `App.js` is currently a class component.  We're transitioning to have all functional components.

Comment: I believe you can use the `Context.Provider` the same way I did. And for the `useEffect` you can use `componentDidMount`.